# Rewrite all the .html links

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, web

On my website, I want to make these URLs:

```
www.example.html/1.html
www.example.html/2.html
www.example.html/3.html
```

appear like these:

```
www.example.html/1
www.example.html/2
www.example.html/3
```

Using Rewrite Rules

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your htaccess file add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

this way you can just go to `www.example.html/1` and all other pages without the need of `.html`